# Maintain state in a multi view app

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have an appdelegate that initiates a view controller that switches between 2 uiviews.

My question is that I want to maintain state. I gather that this is done in the appdelegate applicationWillTerminate. My question is how do I access button text and tableview data from the two views and what is the best way to persist table data?.

Answer (score 0):

To persist the current screen, try using NSUserDefaults:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:0 forKey:kLastOpenedScreenKey];
```

For the others, if you're using a Core Data store and editing the store itself for table data access and modification, as long as you save your managedObjectContext, the reloading should take care of itself. Just make sure to save your data after modifying the store with code like this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
NSError *error;
if (![moc save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Couldn't save!");
}
```

EDIT: if you're not in the appDelegate, and haven't set the managedObjectContext to an instance variable, use this line of code instead:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
```

Comment: thanks Sam is NSManagedObjectContext a good option to save a large tableview?. Also how would I access the tableview and array that is in a different view than the appdelegate, where the save in applicationWillTerminate needs to be triggered?.

Comment: Where are you storing the data for your tableview and array? If you're keeping it in a Core Data store, then as long as you're using the same managedObjectContext in your appDelegate and the view controller with the data source, the save will target everything. I'll update the answer with a different line of code that will help you access the moc from outside the appDelegate.

Comment: If you're not keeping it in a core data store -- say, on a server, or in a plist file somewhere -- then you won't need to worry about doing a specific save, as long as you're saving your data store after each edit.